# How do I go about writing an app that writes to and reads from a centralised data-store?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, shared-data

I've been asked at work to write a simple iPhone app that allows people to write ideas that go to a central depository, which then allows other people in the office to view.

So I'm just wondering what would be the best way to store such data, should I use a simple SQLite database? What Cocoa libraries are used to access/modify the database?

Also, does Apple allow apps to be rolled out to a private network as opposed to going through the App store?

Ideally, each person's login is just their normal Microsoft Outlook email address. Is there a Cocoa library for accessing Microsoft Exchange?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is 4 questions rolled into one, so here are my 4 answers:

1) If your app's purpose is to share information, you shouldn't store anything on the iPhone. Create a simple HTTP server (could be PHP, Ruby, whatever), with a simple interface (GET/POST), with a backing database (could my MySQL, SQL Server, so noSQL, whatever). Make the iPhone send requests to that server, no local storage required.

2) If your database is distant, you'd use NSURLConnection/NSURLRequest (or a Mutable variant). If you use XML, there is a built-in XML facility, if you use JSON, you can use: [JSON Framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/).

3) You can, with an Enterprise account. [Apple Enterprise Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)

4) I don't know about Exchange support. I think you should find something in the SDK though.

Comment: 3) Should I go and write the app first even if I haven't signed up for the Apple Enterprise Developer Program yet? It's all the same isn't it?

Comment: You can, you just won't be able to test on real hardware, only on software Simulator.

Comment: It depends on your platform of choice. Ruby on Rails should provide starting points. There should be plenty PHP+MySQL samples available, etc...